# How do I stop trusting an individual workbook/document in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I accidentally clicked the button to trust a particular document in Excel. However I don't really want to have the macros on this document enabled. I have gone into the Trust Center but the only option on the "Trusted Documents" page is the button to "Clear all Trusted Documents so that they are no longer trusted" which I don't want to do. The document is not in a trusted location so that doesn't help me either. How can I stop trusting this one document please without losing the trust on all the other documents?

Comment: Consider saving the workbook as ***.xlsx***

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Unfortunately it's a shared document and the other users don't have up to date versions of Excel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK I've solved it myself. The key was realising that when I renamed the file the trust was lost. Simply open `regedit` and navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Security\Trusted Documents\TrustRecords`. Delete the entry for the document you no longer trust and voila! the document will no longer be trusted. If your version of Office is different or the Application you are dealing with is not Excel (e.g. Word, Powerpoint, Access or Visio) then the registry path will be slightly different but should be easy to find.

I found the following pages were useful references on trusted documents in the registry although none of them contained the actual answer:

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d0a4090f-9ac8-41c6-9e9c-95c2ef0c247a/trusted-document-set-via-registry

  - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b500c52e-43e1-4e52-a8e9-464380cb252f/access-2010-is-there-a-visible-trusted-documents-list
  - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office2010/2009/09/28/trusted-documents/

Answer (score 0):

While renaming the file certainly works, and so does removing the entry for the filename in the registry -- in cases where the file HAS to be the same name--and the Registry is not accessible due to security restrictions (as it is on most Work computers) there still seems to be no option to simply remove trust on an individual document without resorting to the nuclear option of removing it on all documents, which is often not workable and just a lazy, awful "solution" from Microsoft.  Microsoft should give a simple option for this (likely) common requirement.

Answer (score -1):

**Try these steps to Disable the Macro.**

1. Click on the Developer Tab then hit the Macro Security button.
2. Click on Macro Settings then Click either Disable all macros without 
   notification, or Disable all macros with notification, depending on whether 
   you want to get notification.
3. Select Trusted Publishers, Click on a publisher, then click "Remove"
   to get them off of the list.
4. Select Trusted Locations, Click Disable all Trusted Locations, if
   you want to disable macros for all Excel spreadsheets, regardless of
   where the file is located.

   **Now, the issue is how to disable Macro for the Workbook. For this instead 
   of Step 4 perform Change Trust Location show below.**
5. Select Trusted Documents, Click next to Disable Trusted Documents to
   open trusted documents without macros.
6. Click OK to close the window, then click the "X" to close the Excel.
7. Either Double-click the Excel spreadsheet to open or open in usual way.

**NB:** *It will open up with its macros disabled. You may or may not see a message telling you that macros were disabled, depending on your selection on the Macro Settings screen.*

**To skip Step 4 you can perform Change Trust Location.**

1. Hit File Options.
2. Click Trust Center, Trust Center Settings, Trusted Locations.
3. In the Trusted Locations list, select a location, and then click
    Modify.
4. Change the modifications, and then click OK.

**NB: In the New Location (File Folder Path) store only the Workbook for, the Macro is required to be disabled.**

*I do hope this help you.*

Comment: Just write, what is wrong with the answer because it's the best possible method to Stop Trust the Macro for particular Workbook!!

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted but this answer disables all trusted documents which is not what I want. I only want to stop this one document from being trusted.

Comment: @Caltor,, may be you have not noticed the NB and the lines after it. I've suggested to perform SKIP STEP 4 instead of the STEP 4. Change Trust Location,, allow you to store ONLY the WORKBOOK in new location for which you need the MACRO DISABLE. Let me do some modification in the answer.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not following you. You seem to be suggesting that I point the trusted location to the location of the workbook which I don't want to trust. That doesn't make sense to me. In any event I have now resolved this myself thank you and posted an answer accordingly.